# Auto login after password reset?

Tags: login, password

I like the setting `autoLoginAfterAccountActivation`. Is there something similar to log in users after a password reset?

I can approximate this by using the `users.onSetPassword event`, confirming the user isn't already logged in (i.e. using a normal set password form), and confirming that the user model doesn't have an unverifiedEmail value (i.e. is a brand new user), and then using `craft->userSession->loginByUserId()` but this seems like a very roundabout and potentially stupid way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently nothing native like that. The full list of Craft config settings can be found [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings).

You might want to consider adding this as a [feature request](https://feedback.buildwithcraft.com), though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using the following hidden field in your template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="path/after_reset">
```

See this page for more details: [Craft Set Password Form Template](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/set-password-form)